Flutter: Enforcing an orientation doesn't work for all iOS versions?
I have a problem with the orientation of the CameraPreview in flutter.
It always switched to landscape mode when I turned it which also distorted
the image it was recording. I did not want this, so I added the following to the main.dart:
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);


This fixed the problem for android but iOS was still bugging. So, I added the following to the info.plist:
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
        <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
        <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
            <true/>

and on my iPhone iOS 11 17.6.1, this did the trick. However, on other people's iPhones (iPhone 14, 17.5.1; iPhone 13 Pro, 17.6.1) this did not solve the issue. The os is still turning the screen and thus distorting or showing the preview in a really small window at the top of the screen.
I have to admit: I am clueless of how to proceed due to my code working on some devices and some not.
Do you have any hint or idea?
Much appreciated!
